# Who is Su Beifong's father?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

I strongly believe that Su's father could actually be Sokka. Not just because she looks so much like him, though look closely at her facial expression and think about Sokka making that exact reaction.

[image: Su]

It has been clarified that Lin and Su are half sisters. It has already been said that Kanto was Lin's father and that the relationship didn't work out. It only makes sense that if Sokka was a father to one of Toph's daughters, that he would be Su's.

Here's some more reasons as to why this is even possible:

- when it comes to making strategies Su is really good at them just like Sokka.
- When she was younger she was as sarcastic as Sokka. lastly...
- Su's second oldest son, Huan Beifong reminds me too much of constantly annoyed Sokka, or Sokka trying to think of a new sarcastic comment to make..

[image]

Comment: Came across this from the review queue. I cleaned it up a bit for you, and removed the secondary question you added. Each post here should be a single question - so ask another one! :)

Comment: I think it was deliberately left unanswered. I, for one, really WANT Sokka to have been Toph's other baby-daddy though-- have always been a fan of that particular ship.

Answer (score 13):

## Unknown

During the last few episodes of *Legend of Korra*, the show page on Nick.com (the network for the show) added some images, and a video, discussing the family trees of all the major characters. It has since been taken down, but was [preserved on this site](http://avatarthelastairbenderonline.com/family-tree-korra/). The Beifong family tree marks Su's father as "Unknown".

[image: Beifong Family Tree]

Note that this person is listed separately from Kanto (Lin's father), which matches how Su and Lin describe themselves as half-sisters.

You mentioned Sokka as being a potential father. According to his tree, he did not marry, nor did he have children.

[image: Aang family tree]

So there is no official information revealing Su's father, other than it is not Lin's father. Anything else is speculation and fanfic fodder.

Answer (score 0):

In the graphic novel trilogy The Rift, Toph meets Satoru, who expresses great interest in her metalbending ability. Despite not admitting it to her friends, she does show her "softer side" as Sokka remarks, while around Satoru. When I was re-reading, I noticed that Satoru's hair looks distinctly like Su's curls. Satoru is a mechanic who is just as witty as Sokka, but less of a comedian.

[image: Image result for satoru the rift][image: Image result for satoru the rift]

Now, to debunk the others. The theory that Sokka is Su's father doesn't sit well with me. The "proof" used by the past two speculations is mostly irrelavent. The expressions of the characters depends on the style of the show, so Huan's constantly annoyed expression is not only reminiscent of Sokka, but every other character in both ATLA and LOK. Though it wasn't brought up here, a common arguement is brought up concerning Su's darker skin, that it has to come from Sokka. However, Toph's father, Lao Beifong, has the exact skin tone as Su. Don't forget the similar eye shape!

[image: Image result for lao beifong]

Her wit and sassiness don't have to come from Sokka, Toph herself is very sassy, and Satoru is very intelligent. Though he is not as blunt as Toph, he still wasn't afraid to stick up for himself against her pushing him around. Their story was never wrapped up, leaving a loose end, which is wrapped up by this theory.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is maybe Su might be the daughter of Aang considering her daughter Opal is an airbender but Opal doesn't look anything like her other siblings.  Other possibility is Opal is not Su's daughter but her niece. Lin probably like her mother Toph had an affair in the military and it was hinted she knew Bhumi (Aang's son) well who happens to be a military whiz.  To hide the shame she had her sister raise Opal as her own as Su already had a tarnished name.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Everything after the first sentence is unrelated to the question.  The first sentence introduces a theory, but doesn't fully develop it; if Su's father is Aang, why wouldn't all her children have some resemblance to him?